# How does this implementation of `init` work?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, fold, accumulate

I'm learning Haskell and I found an interesting implementation of `init` using `foldr`. However, I have difficulty understanding how it works.

```
init' xs = foldr f (const []) xs id
    where f x g h = h $ g (x:)
```

Consider I have an input of `[1,2,3]`, then is would become

`f 1 (f 2 ( f 3 (const []))) id`

I substitute those parameters into `f` and the innermost one becomes `h $ (const []) (1:)`, which is simply `h []`. However, when I want to reduce the expression further, I find it hard to grasp. The next one becomes `f 2 (h [])` , which is

`h $ (h []) (2:)`

if it works like that. This looks confusing to me. To match the type of `foldr`, `h` should be of type `[a] -> [a]` and `h []` would just be of type `[a]`, which isn't applicable to `(2:)`.

I also thought about it in another way, that `f x g` returns a function of type `([a] -> [a]) -> [a]`, this kinda makes sense considering applying `id` afterwards. But then I realized I still don't know what this `h` is doing here. It looks like `h` conveys `g (x:)` from last time into the next application.

Did I miss something when I think about doing `fold` with function as accumulator?

I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: You can't reduce to `h []` in that way, since `h` is undefined: no argument was passed, at this time, for that. You can instead reduce to `\h -> h []`, which represents the fact that `h` must still be provided later on. Continue from that: `f 2 (\h -> h []) = ...`

Comment: `foldr` only passes two arguments to `f`. After the substitution, you're left with `\h -> h $ (const []) (1:)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a list `[1,2,3]`, the `init'` is substituted by:

```
init' [1,2,3]
  = foldr f (const []) [1,2,3] id
  = f 1 (foldr f (const []) [2,3]) id
```

Here `f` is thus called with `1` as `x`, `foldr f (const []) [2,3]` as `g` and `id` `h`, this thus means that the this is resolved to:

```
id (foldr f (const []) [2,3] (1:))
```

It thus means that instead of using `id` in the recursion, we now will prepend `1:` to the result. Next we can resolve the inner `foldr` to:

```
foldr f (const []) [2,3] (1:)
 = f 2 (foldr f (const []) [3]) (1:)
 = (1:) (foldr f (const []) [3] (2:))
```

The inner `foldr` then results in:

```
foldr f (const []) [3] (2:)
 = f 3 (foldr f (const []) []) (2:)
 = (2:) (foldr f (const []) [] (3:))
```

finally the `foldr f (const []) []` will resulve to `const []`.

This thus means that:

```
foldr f (const []) [3] (2:)
 = f 3 (foldr f (const []) []) (2:)
 = (2:) (foldr f (const []) [] (3:))
 = (2:) (const [] (3:))
```

The `const` will thus ignore the argument `(3:)`, and return an empty list. So the result of `foldr f (const []) [3] (2:)` is `[2]`:

```
foldr f (const []) [3] (2:)
 = f 3 (foldr f (const []) []) (2:)
 = (2:) (foldr f (const []) [] (3:))
 = (2:) (const [] (3:))
 = (2:) []
 = [2]
```

If we substitute this in the `foldr f (const []) [2,3] (1:)`, we get:

```
foldr f (const []) [2,3] (1:)
 = f 2 (foldr f (const []) [3]) (1:)
 = (1:) (foldr f (const []) [3] (2:))
 = (1:) [2]
 = [1,2]
```

so that means that `init' [1,2,3]` will return `[1,2]`.

This thus means that a

```
foldr f (const []) [x1, x2, …, xn] (x0:)
```

will be replaced by:

```
(x0:) (foldr f (const []) [x2, x3, …, xn] (x1:))
```

If the list gets exhausted, then it will replace:

```
foldr f (const []) [] (xn:)
```

with:

```
const [] (xn:)
```

so the last element will be ignored by the `const` function.